# iPhone layout(created by IB) messed up in simulator

Tags: ios, interface-builder

i was adjusted layout of my app, one question haunts me see below screenshot:
[image]

(please ignore the Chinese characters)

the image is included in a scroll view which be set at position (0, 0)
the red area is the UIVivew which is the superview of the scroll view

why a gap existing between scroll view and UIView? maybe something invisible element hold the place?

TW, all of that is fine in IB editor. really thanks for your help.

Comment: whats the image view content mode you have set? could it be possible that your image is not exactly of that aspect ratio?

Comment: hi @calvinBhai, views should be default mode caused of i haven't set mode of any view by manual. i did another test based on your comments which replace the image view as a UITextView, it seems like couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: what happens if you set the imagview mode to scale to fill? My guess is, currently your image aspect ratio is intact, because of which you see the gap. making it scale to fill will make sure there is no gap, but that'd stretch the image. (and whats the green background down there? is that expected?)

Comment: i tried use UITextView couldn't solve the problem so i guess maybe not related to image aspect ratio, is there something invisible but take place such as an UIToolbar? the green area is a page control element, i do want: scrollView.height(image) + pageControl.height(green area) = UIView.height(UIView.height is:480 - 20(status bar height) - TabBar.height - navigationBar.height)...well, it's all of that. i will tring to change image aspect ratio stretch image to see if it's fix the problem,thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case you are able to set min os requirement to 5.x or later, then you can use http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html to do this.

Comment: UIPageViewControll is great, but i am a little confused about view controller and view, i am going to learn how to use that after everything is clear. I have resolved the problem, scroll view covers all of parent UIView if the scroll view be added into screen programatically, maybe it's a bug of interface builder. thanks calvinBhai, you are very enthusiastic, really appreciate that.